# How to remove Task json properties in Nancy.Response.AsJson

Tags: json, asynchronous, .net-core, task, nancy

I've made one of my API endpoints and inner logic asynchronous and when previously I've used Response.AsJson(Foo.bar()) , it would return the json representation normally, but now I see this appended to it:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "59d680cc734d1d08b4e6c89c",
            "properties": {
                "name": "value"
            }
        }
    ],
    "id": 3,
    "exception": null,
    "status": 5,
    "isCanceled": false,
    "isCompleted": true,
    "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
    "creationOptions": 0,
    "asyncState": null,
    "isFaulted": false
}
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
    "id": "59d680cc734d1d08b4e6c89c",
        "properties": {
            "name": "value"
        }
```

As I understand, it's because I've wrapped my object in a Task , but I can't figure out, how with Nancy framework, which I use the Response.AsJson, to make it so the properties are excluded. I can obviously omit the Response.AsJson of the returned object, but then response is no longer Json if requesting through web-browser for example.

For further example

NancyModule for routing API:

```
public ItemCatalogModule(IItemCatalog itemCatalog) : base("/itemCatalog")
    {    
        Get("/fetch/{id}", async parameters =>
        {
            var id = (string)  parameters.id;
            var response = await Response.AsJson(itemCatalog.GetItem(id));
            return response;

        });
    }
```

How the interface looks like of ItemCatalog:

```
public interface IItemCatalog
{
    Task<Item> GetItem(string id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud do this :

```
public ItemCatalogModule(IItemCatalog itemCatalog) : base("/itemCatalog")
{    
    Get("/fetch/{id}", async parameters =>
    {
        var id = (string)  parameters.id;
        return Response.AsJson(await itemCatalog.GetItem(id));

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But could you please elaborate why the positioning of await syntax gives different results? Is this something that is specific to C# asynchronous rules or nancyfx framework?

Comment: `await` says wait for the result then return it as Json as opposed to return the Task being returned by your method.